# Database queries to 'new-database' are not allowed in this test

Tags: django, django-testing, multiple-databases, django-database, django-tests

I have added a new database in my django project. Now I have run into issues with my test cases. I am keep getting this error message for every single of my test cases:

```
Database queries to 'new-database' are not allowed in this test
```

I have searched for this issue and the common solution comes down to adding `databases = '__all__'` or `databases = {'default', 'new_database'}` to the TestCase class

But the problem is that now we have a lot of these test cases in my django application and a lot of corresponding TestCase based classes. So it does not fill right (specifically from the scale point of view) to add this `databases = '__all__'` declaration or whatever to every single class.

Do we have any other and more proper solution for this issue?

(After all why django needs to make transaction to `new_database` in all other test cases every single time that does not seem needed at all?)